# How would I extend the wagtailmenus LinkPage to add a generic picture

Tags: wagtail

I have been using the `AbstractLinkPage` model from wagtailmenus in my site for a while now. I find it quite useful.
Source: [wagtailmenus AbstractLinkPage model](https://wagtailmenus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/abstractlinkpage.html?highlight=linkpage#implementing-abstractlinkpage-into-your-project)

My site is building cards from children pages and adds banner images from children pages automatically to these cards. Some of the children pages are `LinkPages`.
How can I extend the subclassed `LinkPage` (from `AbstractLinkPage`) to add a generic image which can be used as a card image?

I have added the field:

```
class LinkPage(AbstractLinkPage):
    card_image = models.ForeignKey(
        get_image_model_string(),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='+',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

    content_panels = AbstractLinkPage.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel("card_image"),
    ]
```

However the image *card_image* field does not show in the admin interface.

Any help to move forward is appreciated.

Comment: Did you add `card_image` to the `LinkPages's` content_panels?

Comment: Thanks @NicoGriffioen! It does not show the card image field after adding `card_image` to content panels. I have updated the code in my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wagtailmenus uses it's own tabbed interface (in wagtailmenus.panels):

```
linkpage_tab = ObjectList(
    linkpage_panels, heading=_("Settings"), classname="settings"
)

linkpage_edit_handler = TabbedInterface([linkpage_tab])
```

So what you have to do is to create a new ObjectList:

```
from wagtailmenus.panels import linkpage_panels
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import ObjectList, TabbedInterface

my_linkpage_tab = ObjectList(
    linkpage_panels + [ImageChooserPanel("card_image")], 
    heading=_("Settings"), classname="settings"
)
```

.. and add it to your class:

```
class LinkPage(AbstractLinkPage):
    [..]

    edit_handler = TabbedInterface([my_linkpage_tab])
```